# capture history state on refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have a page that refreshes itself after a certain time. I would like to display console message "first time load" only on initial load. I tried reading history state, but after page refresh the state is erased and I keep on getting my "first time load" message. Please advise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
console.log(history.state);
if (!history.state) {
    console.log("first time load");
}
history.pushState("reload", null, "#reload");
console.log(history.state);  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
if (!sessionStorage.getItem("reloaded")){
    alert('first time!');
}
//...
sessionStorage.setItem("reloaded", true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```